# Create editable Template with multiple models in one form

Tags: python, django, forms, view, models

i read a lot of forms.
i want to edit userinformation, but the userinformation is existed of two models.

```
One model this:

class Tc(LoginUser):
    link = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    contact = models.OneToOneField(Contact, blank=True, null=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

And the second one:

```
class Contact(models.Model):
    contact_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

Now i want to edit "contact" field. 
It should be controled, if a contact is existing, if not, so create a new. If there is an existing one, then update this.

My problem is that, that i must use two forms and i dont know how exactly.

Comment: You can read about modelforms at the django site https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#module-django.forms.models

Answer (score 0):

You need to make queries : for handle contact and know about a contact existing you need [Making queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/queries/#making-queries)
. as a hint for check about existing if you have one `unique` object of contact like `check_name` you can do it with following :

```
from models import Contact

contats=contact.objects.all()
for n in contacts:
   if n.first_name == check_name()
   #do something
   else:
   #do something
```